# How to initialise a 2D array in Hyperledger Fabric .cto file?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Is there any way to initialise a 2D array in a Hyperledger .cto file?

What I want to do:

```
o String[][] csv optional
```

But its thowing an error -  and will only allow:

```
o String[] csv optional
```

Does anyone know how to get around this? Or does anyone know how to do an array of arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this, with a concept:

```
concept S1 {
  o String[] csv
}

asset S2 identified by sID {
  o String sID
  o S1 [] s1 
}
```

Example data would look like:

```
{
  "$class": "org.acme.model.S2",
  "sID": "SR26",
  "s1": [{"csv":["a","b"]},{"csv":["c","d"]}]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply R Thatcher, I tried what you detailed above. Im having problems associating a value to s1 though: ex for a simple 2x2 array:

`s1= [["part id", "part name"],["1", "Wing"]];`

I get this error however: ` s1 has value ["part id","part name"] (object) expected type String[]`
Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest trying my model AND example data in Playground.  It is not a real 2D array - just a suggestion of how you could achieve something similar.